# Cannot pick Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I'm trying to use a microphone on my Bluetooth headset in Ubuntu 18.04 and can't - it is never listed in the settings so I cannot even choose it to enable or configure.

[image]

When I select `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)` - selection is not saved. It doesn't throw any error - so lets me pick it without the problem, but when I close the window and open it again `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` is selected again. So I guess that's the root of the problem - that I cannot pick `HSP/HFP`. But why can't I? And why there's no error or warning thrown?

Comment: I have the same issue, but on the reverse. It seems that the root issue is that the choice is not preserved.